# Does iPadOS have the same file access permission system on internal and external storage?

Tags: permission, ipados

Need to know whether data on external storage such as USB drive is as safe as (or, as sandboxed as) data on internal storage in iPadOS.

This is my understanding of the file access persmission system of iPadOS:

1.Built-in apps by Apple can access any user data(e.g. pictures and other data files) on the internal storage.

2.3rd party apps cannot access data on internal storage, except for data in the data folder of the App. To access data outside the data folder, the app need to bring out the system files picker window and the user select some data in the window, after that, the system will allow the app to access exactly those data.

Is my understanding right? Does iPasOS have the same file access permission system for data external storage?

Comment: Bear in mind that anyone can plug in that drive on a Mac and read everything. Is your goal just to prevent your apps on your iPad from accessing your files without permission?

Comment: @benwiggy Yes, not Mac, Mac is open system like Windows. iPadOS and iOS are sandboxed OS.

Comment: So what are you trying to achieve, exactly?

Comment: @benwiggy Trying to be sure that no 3rd party app can access data on external storage.